# CAML viewfields

Tags: camlviewfields

When using CAML to extract from a list, what is the purpose of the viewfields in the query - to set value types - text, interger,etc. - and make the fields available so the get_item('fieldname') method can pull the data from them? If the viewfields is omitted can you use the get_item('fieldname') method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<ViewFields>` is used in the CAML query to define that how many fields you want to retrieve by executing the query.
If we did not define `<ViewFields>` then it will retrieve all the columns of list.

For example if I define ViewFields like:

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
    <FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef>
</ViewFields>
```

then it will retreive only two columns ID & Titile from the list.

It's not mandatory to set `<ViewFields>`.

**Read more**: [SPQuery.ViewFields Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Are you saying that since only the two fields are being retrieved these are the only two fields that the get_item method will display -  get_item(departmentname') would not return anything?

Comment: Yes, it will retrieve only those fields which are defined in ViewFields. To get the 'departmentname' field you have to include that field in ViewFields like <FieldRef Name="departmentname"></FieldRef>

Comment: Thanks. I'm using JS so your link was much help but appreciated.

Comment: Welcomes .. :) @PianoMan

Comment: This doesn't work if the field is empty.

Answer (score 7):

- `ViewFields` basically gives you option to reduce data in response.
- It allows you to specify which fields you want in return for your query.

It is always a **best practice** to use `ViewFields` as and when possible.

Also in conjunction with [SPQuery.ViewFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields(v=office.14).aspx) you must use [SPQuery.ViewFieldsOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfieldsonly(v=office.14).aspx), then only it will return only those column, else it is going to return all column in response.

For Ex:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

query.Query = <<YOUR QUERY GOES HERE>>
query.ViewFields = "<ViewFields>"+
    "<FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>"+
    "<FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef>"+
"</ViewFields>";

query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

Comment: Are you saying that in addition to the fields requested by viewfieilds ALL the fields are available to the get_item('fieldname') method?

I like the idea of using the only feature. I have never seen that appear in any of the examples I have come across.  I'll have to look into that.

Thanks

Comment: sure @PianoMan . I hope you must have tried it by now

Answer (score 1):

In the list views, Viewfields are essentially the columns that you see in the list view.